# Detect href link click in react native webview

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-webview

```
<WebView
    bounces={false}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={{ uri:"https://www.google.com" }}
    mixedContentMode={'never'} // security
    startInLoadingState={true} // when starting this component
    onMessage={onMessage}
    javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
/>
```

I am using the above code in the webview. I want that as we are doing google search get some results. So i that when any user click on any link then i will detect that user click. Only user clicked link not navigation. So can i inject any javascript callback on link click. So that i can perform some task on user click.

Like i want modify user clicked link. Suppose user clicked on 'wikipedia.com' and i want to add some keys in this url and then user will redirect to modified url like this/

wikipedia.com/?user-clicked